# Convergence of rows and columns of infinite matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following.

> Let $(e_n)_n$ and $(f_n)_n$ be orthonormal sequences in a Hilbert Space $H$.
> Let's define the infinite matrix $A = (a_{ij}) = \langle e_i,f_j\rangle$.
> I need to show that the sequences given by the rows and columns of the matrix are convergent. Determine wether the diagonal is convergent or not.

Let's fix $i$, then consider the sequence $(a_{in})_n = (\langle e_i,f_n\rangle)_n$, by Bessel's Inequality for $x = e_i\in H, \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty|\langle e_i,f_n\rangle|^2 \leq ||e_i||^2 = 1.$ Therefore, the series is convergent, then the term goes to 0, and so does the general term of the sequence. A similar argument shows the same for fixed $j.$

However, I'm stuck when considering the diagonal. My intuition tells me that it could be divergent but I don't know the reason why. Honestly, without any additional hypothesis I don't see what can be said about the sequence $(\langle e_n,f_n\rangle)_n$ or on the contrary, find a counterexample.

Comment: You know that all the entries, including the diagonal ones, have magnitude at most 1. So for a counterexample the simplest thing you could aim for is $0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots.$

Comment: You may consider $f_i=e_{\sigma(i)}$ for an appropriate permutation of the natural numbers.